# Time-To-Live for inserted entries with a Vertica database?

Tags: database, vertica

Is that possible to set up a Time-To-Live for inserted entries with a Vertica database?
if Yes at which level ..? table ? a entire database ? a simple entry ?

Comment: you mean - An event that will drop some data depending on it's life-time ?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Vertica does not have this capability. You can try using a [temporary table](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#14298.htm) which allows for the table to be dropped once rows are committed in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Vertica does not handle this types of events native, but it can be done.

1. Use UDF's to this for you.
2. Use Talend or Pentaho to plan a job to do this task.

**Advice:** 
 - Vertica does not handle well often deletes, and if you choose to do this make sure you tune up you DB well to hanlde this type of work.

*Question : What is this for ? Maybe there is a better solution for it !*